# PHP: How can I get the contents of a CSV file into a MySQL database row by row?

Tags: php, mysql, csv

How can I get the contents of a CSV file into a MySQL database row by row? Ive tried a few methods but can never get more than one row returned, using fgetcsv. One method I've tried that seemed to come so close to working:

```
    $fileName = $_FILES['SpecialFile']['name'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['SpecialFile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['SpecialFile']['size'];

    if(!$fileSize) 
    {
        echo "File is empty.\n";
        exit;
    }

    $fileType = $_FILES['SpecialFile']['type'];
    $file = fopen($tmpName, 'r');

    if(!$file) 
    {
        echo "Error opening data file.\n";
        exit;
    }

    while(!feof($file))
    {
        $data = str_replace('"','/"',fgetcsv($file, filesize($tmpName), ","));

        $linemysql = implode("','",$data);

        $query = "INSERT INTO $databasetable VALUES ('$linemysql')";

        return mysql_query($query);

    }

    fclose($file);
```

only enters one row, but if I print_r $data it returns all the rows. How do I get it to insert all th rows?

Another method:

```
    $data = str_getcsv($csvcontent,"\r\n","'","");

    foreach($data as &$Row) 
    {
        $linearray = str_getcsv($Row,',',''); //parse the items in rows 

        $linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);

        echo $query = "INSERT INTO $databasetable VALUES ('$linemysql')";
    }
```

This almost works too, but there is text within the csv that also contains new lines, so I dont know howto split the actual rows and not the new lines in the text as well.??

Comment: Post the code you are using. Have you tried running the example shown in the manual? http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

Comment: Can you post code examples of what you have tried? Also, can provide error details - if any? It could be an issue with your script, or it could be a MySQL issue with table definition (a common one is a primary key that is not set to auto-increment).

Comment: *(tip)* http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: any reason you can't use load data infile ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Am I missing something (not much PHP experience) - doesn't that return statement in the while loop explain the described behavior? How can that loop run more than once?

Comment: @f00: not exactly sure what that will do, but fields from the .CSV must match with fields in the DB. Maybe explain basicly what that will do?

Comment: @Morre: technically it cant, but im not sure howto make it run more than one and still return more than a single row.

Comment: So the return is definitely wrong. If you want to collect the results create an array before entering the loop and collect the results in that array, return that array after the loop and after fclose(). I don't see why you need any return value of mysql_query, unless to check if the SQL succeeded (true/false). EDIT: I just checked, mysql_result returns true/false for INSERT statements. So no need to collect those return values anyway, just make sure to raise/handle an error when there's false and continue when true.

Comment: @Morre: Yes but I am still unsure of how to create said array.

Comment: (I edited my previous response) Don't - you only get true/false anyway. If false there was an error (no idea what your app needs/wants to do in such a case), if true do nothing.
if (!mysql_query($query))
{
   ERROR HANDLING
}

Comment: @Morre: But i dont know how to get more than one row from the CSV file? I know a foreach loop will be used at some point, but I dont know what data to use with it.

Comment: What happens when you just remove that "return"

Comment: @Morre: hmmm it almost works if return is removed, it claims there are MySQL syntax errors.

Comment: I thought so. Can't help with the syntax error - but if you expect help here you should provide more specific info... exact message and code (line numbers?) for the error.

Comment: The errors are in MySQL itself, You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')INSERT INTO tmdata VALUES ('1082','2795714','03063','','True','6716','=No.1 Fit' at line 1

Comment: @Morre: actually it works now. My error checking was checking to see if the function returned something. with the return missing it always errored.

Comment: Or not... its only entering half if the rows

Comment: @Morre: it looks like every second mysql_query is failing, any ideas? also the implode function fails so i put an if statment around it to detect if the array its beinmg sent is empty. but im not sure thats the right fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function return an array from csv file

```
function CSVImport($file) {
    $handle = fopen($file, 'r');
    if (!$handle)
        die('Cannot open  file.');
    $rows = array();
    //Read the file as csv
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {

        $rows[] =  $data

    }

    fclose($handle);

    return $rows;
}
```

// this will return an array 
// make some logic to read the array and save it

```
$csvArray = CSVImport($tmpName);
        if (count($csvArray)) {
             foreach ($csvArray as $key => $value) {

                  // $value is a row of adata 

              }
          }
```

Comment: This preforms the same function as the code already in existance, however it still only returns 230 of the 464 rows in the CSV file. :(

Comment: `$csvArray = $this->CSVImport($tmpName);
  
  if (count($csvArray)) 
  {
   foreach ($csvArray as $key => $value) 
   {
   
    if($value != '')
    {
     $linemysql = implode("','",$value);
    }
    
    echo $query = "INSERT INTO $databasetable VALUES ('$linemysql') ";
    
    if(mysql_query($query) === false)
    {
     $errors++;
    }
   
   }
  }`

Comment: in your case use : LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myFile.csv' REPLACE INTO TABLE targetTable  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 [LOAD DATA DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/load-data.html)

Comment: @cranberies: problem is the data comes from a uploaded file, not from just a location. Also unless that script will know the diff between actual /n and /n's within data of the array then it will fail.

Comment: That does depend on the content of the uploaded file, but i will try it a bit later to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
function getCSVcontent($filePath) {
    $csv_content = fopen($filePath, 'r');

    while (!feof($csv_content)) {
        $rows[] = fgetcsv($csv_content,1000,";");
    }
    fclose($csv_content);
    return $rows;
}
```

Make sure that you new line separator is ";" or give the correct one to fgetcsv(). Regards.